# Mailing email highly-available for appliances which don't support MX records?

Tags: email

I am replacing the Mailservers for my organization.

I notice that some devices such as printers, a Fax-to-email gateway, a Google Mini search appliance do not support MX records, and require a hostname (The A record) or IP address of a mailserver. These devices must connect to an SMTP server directly. They only allow a single host, and do not support multiple hostnames in the field.

Connecting directly to an SMTP server is bad, as there is no redundancy in case that particular server is unavailable. MX records exist for this reason, if a client is unable to connect to the first server (by priority) in the MX record it will move on to the next server.

We need redundancy, because these devices are used in some of our business processes. How can I make mail delivery be redundant in this case?

I need email sent from these devices to be highly

This is easy to do with Sendmail and Postfix. But I have not found an adequate solution for these appliances.

Comment: What about some form of NLB redirecting to one or more SMTP servers? (Not sure it's possible, so guessing == comment, not an answer.)

Comment: Network Loadbalancing is possible, but not sure we want to invest the effort.